# The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I have been stuck with this issue for 3 days. I have tried all sorts of solutions including deleting all dependencies and reinstalling them, clearing catches, changing to different dependencies.

Nothing seems to work.

My pom.xml file looks like this (only relevant part included).

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>boxes</groupId>
<artifactId>boxes</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>KlaraLan</name>
<description>Boxes</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <!--<relativePath />  lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile -->
    <dependency>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.expressly</groupId>
        <artifactId>expressly</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And my config file has this:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validatorFactory() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

and my controller method looks like this:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@POST
@Path(value = "saveApplication")
public @ResponseBody
PublicApplicationForm saveApplication(
            @ApiParam(value = "Ping job input parameter", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody PublicPingJobRequest ping) {
        return LanBO.savePublicApplicationForm(ping);
}
```

But no matter what i do i keep getting this error:

Description:

```
The Bean Validation API is on the classpath but no implementation could be found

Action:

Add an implementation, such as Hibernate Validator, to the classpath.
```

Any one that had a similar issue and can help?

Comment: It might not be related, because this is not the usual error message, but a very common problem is that Hibernate Validator needs an implementation of Jakarta EL. One that works is `org.glassfish:jakarta.el`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Spring Boot 2.6 which supports Bean Validation 2.0. Bean Validation 2.0 is implemented by Hibernate Validator 6.2 but you're trying to use 8.0. 8.0 implements Bean Validation 3.0 which is only supported by Spring Boot 3.

Hibernate Validator is a dependency of `spring-boot-starter-validation` so you should remove this dependency from your pom:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

You should then also update your `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency to remove the `<version>`:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This will allow the version to be controlled by Spring Boot's dependency management and avoid mixing Spring Boot 3.0 and 2.6 in the same app which will not work.

Comment: Thank you let me give it a try. and ill get back too you.

Comment: Well that worked but now its not validating anything ?? iv been here before it takes null values yet i have used @NotNull on the PublicPingJobRequest

Comment: fixed it a @valid annotation was missing on a subclass. but your solution was correct.